# How to free XBox 360 storage on XBox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, call-of-duty-ghosts

So, basically, I want to download the Nemesis Map Pack on Call of Duty: Ghosts. As you may know, CoD:Ghosts is a 360 game that is backward compatible on Xbox One. When I go to the download screen, it says;
"Available Space: 504.69 MB"
"Required Space: 1.56 GB"
Normally, I would download it just to see if it is incorrect, and if it wasn't, I'd just uninstall it. The thing is, this map pack costs $14.99+tax. I don't want to waste $16 on this map pack if I can't play it. So that's what I'm asking you. What do I do?
P.S.: I already tried "Clear Local XBox 360 Data"

Answer (score 0):

Xbox One and Xbox 360 storage are on the same hard drive. You need to clear around 1 GB of storage from your Xbox, so clearing your local Xbox 360 storage (which clears only your Xbox 360 profiles and game saves) won't be enough. You can make space by going to Settings -> System -> Storage -> Manage storage ->  Uninstall things and then select what games/apps you would like to remove to make more space.